# Where is my database located of my MacOS app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, macos-sierra

What is the database location of a MacOS application when using Core Data ?

I searched everywhere on my Mac and did't find it.
I Have the hidden files OFF and I'm sure there is data in my database.
Also I don't use app Sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the `persistentStoreCoordinator` method in your `AppDelegate.m`. There is a line

```
NSURL *applicationDocumentsDirectory = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
```

Just add

```
NSLog(@"myDirectory: %@", applicationDocumentsDirectory);
```

This assumes you started your project with Xcode 8 Cocoa template with "use Core Data" option.

Or add

```
NSLog(@"Array of CD stores: %@", self.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores);
```

to `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, for example. The resulting path should be in your user's library `Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/<whatever>/<appname>.storedata`.

Comment: thank you. The DB was in the folder : com.apple.toolsQA.CocoaApp_CD. Now I need a password to open the app "DB browser for SQLite", where to find it please ?

Comment: Please be more specific. Why do you need "DB Browser for SQLite"? Why does it need a password?

Comment: I want to manage my database in raw, I mean without Xcode. Like you can manage a MySQL DB in MyAdminPHP. So I have an app which can open my .SQLite DB, but it requires a password.

Comment: It normally does not need a password for opening a DB file. I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

If you have sandboxing enabled for your app, it will be placed under `~/Library/Containers/app.bundle.id/Data/Library/Application Support/AppTargetName` where app.bundle.id is the Bundle Identifier specified in your app's target and AppTargetName is the name of that target, i.e. the name of the generated .app file. In that folder you should find the SQLite files that contain the database data.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.

Answer (score 0):

If you construct the PersistentStore with swift code below:

```swift
let storeURL = URL.storeURL(for: "group.readlater.shared", databaseName: databaseName)
let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)
```

The path for the sqlite is specified by the url, and you can print it.

In my case, the file is located in `/Users/<name>/Library/Group Containers/group.<name>.shared` because I enable group containers.